# wcf service (iis hosted) debug issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a problem while hosting my wcf service. When i run Visual Studio as an administrator is ok. But when i don't i get

```
unable to start debugging on the web server iis does not list a website that matches the launched URL
```

I read that i have to turn on Windows Authetntication, but on my IIS i don't have this option, aslo in Program Features on Security i don't have checkbox Windows Authentication.

It's very important to me to find a solution to run my service without running VS as administrator.

[image: iis]

[image: program features]

Comment: Why are you even using IIS for development purposes instead of the more lightweight IIS Express? The advantage of IIS Express is that it is lighter and doesn't have such restrictions as having to run VS as administrator in order to debug. The full blown version of IIS is intended to be installed on servers that will be hosting your application on production.

Comment: because when i use IIS Express it starts on random port (localhost:somenumber) and i want to create virutal directory which runs on specified port (secure https) i get an error "cannot create virutal directory" because it's been already used by another app"

Comment: You could perfectly fine run HTTPS with IIS Express.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov check the pirntscreen below

Comment: No idea. Personally I never had such problems. Probably because I don't even have IIS installed on my development machine. I've always worked with IIS Express. Looks like some conflicts to me but I cannot say what might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem with IIS Express:

Go to "User\Documents\IISExpress\config", edit the file "applicationhost.config" and remove the app which uses the occupied port.